# Deleting selected features using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, features, select-by-attribute, vector-layer, delete

I have a shapefile with only one field `"DN"`. I would like to delete all features which does not have specific value of the field. Let's say the `"DN"` can be 1,2 or 3.

So far I was able to find out how to select Features and how to delete feature, but I did not succeed to combine them. Let's say I want only features with `"DN" = 3` to remain:

Selection of the Features found here : [Filter features based on their attributes using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58614/filter-features-based-on-their-attributes-using-python), however, I do not know if it does what it is supposed to do since I did not find the way how to check what is inside.

```py
select = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u'"DN"!=3'))
```

delete features found in the [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html)

```py
res = Ilayer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures()
```

As far as I know, the `deleteFeatures()` requires `"ID"`s of the features, but I have no idea how to get them from from `select` which is `QgsFeatureIterator`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can loop over the iterator and get the [`id()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Feature/QgsFeature.html#qgis.core.QgsFeature.id) for every feature in it:

```py
with edit(layer):
    # build a request to filter the features based on an attribute
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"DN" != 3')

    # we don't need attributes or geometry, skip them to minimize overhead.
    # these lines are not strictly required but improve performance
    request.setSubsetOfAttributes([])
    request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)

    # loop over the features and delete
    for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
        layer.deleteFeature(f.id())
```

#### or with QGIS < 2.12

```py
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"DN" != 3')
request.setSubsetOfAttributes([])
request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)

ids = [f.id() for f in layer.getFeatures(request)]

layer.startEditing()
for fid in ids:
    layer.deleteFeature(fid)
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Thank you, that was that! I just noticed that the FilterExpression was wrong (not u'"DN"=2||"DN"=1' but u'"DN"!=3' should be used). Please if you would edit your answer for this not to confuse other viewers.

Comment: isn't it layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(ids)?

Comment: Using dataProvider() is possible but I prefer to work directly on the layer since this way the changes are communicated internally (to the map canvas, attribute table...) [and other reasons](http://www.opengis.ch/2015/08/12/with-edit-layer/#avoid-using-dataprovider-methods).

Comment: layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(ids) has thrown crashes for me when layer.deleteFeature(fid) didnt... Bad crashes. The kind that cause a seg fault and kill qgis. The kind that take 6 hours to find... stick with the answer posted here. Bums me out because layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(ids) is all through my code and now I've got to fix it all.

Answer (score 10):

There is also a possibility of using the [`deleteSelectedFeatures()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a1164f0c4b27edfa7acbe57211f41de8a) method from the `QgsVectorLayer` class for deleting selected features:

```py
# choose an active layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# make own selection
field_name = "DN" # specify your field
field_values = (1,2,3) # specify values for features that you want to retain
expression = f'"{field_name}" in {field_values}'
layer.selectByExpression(expression)

# delete selected features
if layer.selectedFeatureCount() > 0:
    layer.startEditing()
    layer.deleteSelectedFeatures()
    layer.commitChanges()
```