# Can't delete features from layer using QGIS' Python API

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I've only recently started using QGIS and it's Python API.
Currently I've loaded two OpenStreetMap datasets. I would like to remove lines with from the second set where the name is already present in the first. 
There is a catch: the first dataset uses a field called `name1` while the second dataset uses a field called `Name`.

What I've tried so far is fairly naive and non-pythonic:

1. Store a list of all the values called `name1` from the first dataset
2. Iterate through all the fields in the second dataset and if `Name` attribute is contained in the `name1` values array above, call QgsVectorLayer's `deleteFeature()` passing the feature's `id()`

In code, the layer I want to delete from is called `Cropped` and the list of all values called `name1` from the first dataset is called `roads` so what I tried looks like this:

```
Cropped.startEditing()
fields = Cropped.getFeatures()
for f in fields:
    name = f.attribute('Name')
    count = roads.count(name)
    if count > 0:
        print 'removing ',name,count
        Cropped.deleteFeature(f.id())
Cropped.commitChanges()
```

`startEditing()` and `commitChanges()` return `True`, but all `Cropped.deleteFeature(f.id())` calls return `False`.

I've also spotted this existing post on [How to delete selected features in Qgis using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112172/how-to-delete-selected-features-in-qgis-using-python) which seems to tackle the exact problem. I am using QGIS version 2.14.0-Essen so I have tried this, based on the answer:

```
with edit(Cropped):
    for fid in fids:
        Cropped.deleteFeature(fid)
```

Where `fids` is a list of field ids that match the condition above.
I get `False` for every single call.

Any hints/tips on what I'm doing wrong/missing ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some vector formats are read-only in QGIS. So, first check if your `Cropped` layer is read-only:

```
Cropped.isReadOnly()
```

If not, then you could use this code snippet to delete all features whose `Name` attribute value is already in the `roads` list (note the handy function to delete all those features in a single step):

```
features = Cropped.getFeatures()
ids = [ f.id() for f in features if f.attribute( 'Name' ) in roads ]
with edit( Cropped ):
    Cropped.deleteFeatures( ids )
```

Comment: That sounds very promising (+1). I can check in a few hours. In case the Cropped layer is a read-only vector format, what's the best way to make them writeable ? (Had a quick peek at the [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html) and Toggle Editing seems like it should work)

Comment: In case it's read-only, you could export it to a writeable format, such as Shapefile (I still don't know what your layer format is). Right click on the layer and click on "Save As...".

Comment: "Save as..." shape file worked like a charm, thank you :)