# Deleting all features of Vector layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, features, vector-layer, delete

I am developing a Python plugin for QGIS. In the QGIS map window, certain features of a vector layer are selected and those features are highlighted. Now I need to delete all the existing features from another vector layer without disturbing the current selection in the map window.

Is it possible to delete all the features of a vector layer without selecting them?

Comment: Please rephrase your question to indicate where you're getting stuck.  Avoid questions that begin with "Is it possible..." as the answer is most likely "Yes".  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the following code which is heavily based on the answer from this post: [How to delete selected features in QGIS using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112172/how-to-delete-selected-features-in-qgis-using-python)

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
with edit(layer):   
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        layer.deleteFeature(feat.id())
```

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to [@GermánCarrillo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4972/germ%c3%a1n-carrillo), a more efficient method could be to delete all features at once:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
with edit(layer):
    listOfIds = [feat.id() for feat in layer.getFeatures()]
    layer.deleteFeatures( listOfIds )
```

Comment: That works perfectly !!

Comment: @Sjs - Awesome, glad it worked =)

Comment: You could remove all features at once with layer.deleteFeatures( listOfIds ).

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - That is indeed a much better approach, many thanks ;)

Comment: For Qgis 3.2 instead of layer.deleteFeatures( listOfIds ) works layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures( listOfIds )

Answer (score 10):

In QGIS 3 one can use the [`truncate()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a4b9ae0ff7bf3bf3cadfb502f4e1af26c) method of the `QgsVectorDataProvider` class.

> Removes all features from the layer.
>
> This requires either the FastTruncate or DeleteFeatures capability.
> Providers with the FastTruncate capability will use an optimised
> method to truncate the layer.

```py
# referring to the original Vector layer
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points")[0]

# accessing Vector layer provider
provider = source_layer.dataProvider()
   
# deleting all features in the Vector layer
provider.truncate()
```

Comment: That's a nice new feature :)

Comment: It is not work in editing mode