# Delete subselected features with PyQGIS and processing

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

In QGIS 3.10, I have layers in which I select features by location (to find duplicates), using :

```
selected_features = processing.run('qgis:selectbylocation', {'INPUT':layer1, 'PREDICATE':0, 'INTERSECT':layer2, 'METHOD':0})
```

`'METHOD':0` means I begin a new selection with the selected features

Then, in this selection, I want to select features by expression, using :

```
subselected_features = processing.run('qgis:selectbyexpression', {'INPUT':layer1, 'EXPRESSION':expression, 'METHOD':3})
```

`'METHOD':3` means I select features in the current selection

Now, I want to delete all the subselected features. I know how to delete features by expression, with the method explained here ([Deleting selected features using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112172/deleting-selected-features-using-pyqgis)) :

```
with edit(layer1):
    # build a request to filter the features based on an attribute
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"DN" != 3')

    # we don't need attributes or geometry, skip them to minimize overhead.
    # these lines are not strictly required but improve performance
    request.setSubsetOfAttributes([])
    request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)

    # loop over the features and delete
    for f in layer1.getFeatures(request):
        layer1.deleteFeature(f.id())
```

But this way selects features in the entire `layer1`. It does not allow to choose a METHOD as with processing, to make a subselection in the current selection.

Does someone has an idea to delete these subselected features ?

Comment: You should change `edit(layer)` into `edit(layer1)`.  Then, I think, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was just an error in the code i copied, but not the source of the problem. I edited the post to correct it. Ben W answer is simply what i needed

Comment: I've QGIS 3.8. Your script worked in it. It might have been the problem.

Comment: The script works, but it does not fill my need. It selects features to delete in the whole layer, whereas I wanted to select features within the current selection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the features you want to delete are already selected it should be as simple as:

```
with edit(layer1):
    layer1.deleteSelectedFeatures()
```

As per the method of QgsVectorLayer class from the docs [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a51adbaac9ac00537a5305480c0dc5967).

Comment: Indeed, very simple, but I didn't find it on the web! Thanks

Comment: No worries @Cupain, you're welcome.