# How to access a feature by specific field value using python ogr in an efficient way?

Tags: python, sql, ogr, feature-class, request

I have one point layer and one polygon layer with a common identifier attribute field called "N", same objects amounts but Feature IDs (FID) are different.

I have to iterate on the first one and what I want is to get the FID from the second using an attribute join (access to FID from the polygon using the specific field value of "N" as a bridge between both layers.

```
for feature in pointsLayer
    bridge = feature.GetField('N')

    # Here I want to select my feature from my other layer 
    # which has the same attribute value "N"
    polygonsLayer.GetFeature(...)
```

As I [read for now](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58614/how-to-get-features-based-on-their-attributes-using-python), I have 2 solutions, SQL request or create a matching table N-idPolygon?

Any hint what would be more efficient? We talk about 10000 features max in each layer.

Comment: It is an exercise or a personal work ? If it is a personal work, look at [Problem intersecting shapefiles with OGR in Python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/176582/2581). It is much easier to work with Fiona (only Python dictionaries and your problem is easy to resolve without SQL or matching table)

Comment: Ty @gene, actually it's a little bit of both, since I like to achieve this operation in a QGIS plugin. Ty for the Fiona tipp, I'll keep it for later use since I do not want to use many more librairies than the ones that are installed on a QGIS 2.2 standard desktop installation. I was actually surprised that there were no simple query function in ogr to get directly a feature from it's field value.